# Docker (stopped container) but still I see processes and lot of memory taken?

Tags: docker

I have stopped the docker container (the docker says exited) but I see a lot processes again and lot of memory taken (KiB Mem : 13183321+total, 86293136 free)?!

```
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13183321+total, 86298728 free,   920048 used, 44614440 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16383996 total, 16383996 free,        0 used. 13004216+avail Mem 


47253 galaxy     20   0  132M  2096   904 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.76 sshd: galaxy@pts/2
47435 root       20   0  408M 13356  8196 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.65 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd://
    1 root       20   0 56768  6824  3976 S  0.0  0.0  0:12.71 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --d
  856 root       20   0 43016  7948  7636 S  0.0  0.0  0:06.00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
  881 root       20   0 45320  4840  2692 S  0.0  0.0  0:03.53 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
 1116 root       16  -4 51148  1592  1216 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.36 /sbin/auditd -n
 1112 root       16  -4 51148  1592  1216 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.79 /sbin/auditd -n
 1757 root       20   0  321M 23212  6272 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --no
 1144 root       20   0  321M 23212  6272 S  0.0  0.0  0:03.46 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --no
 1148 avahi      20   0 28068  1628  1340 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.28 avahi-daemon: running [linux.local]
 1161 root       20   0  203M  5044  4440 S  0.0  0.0  0:01.48 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 1162 root       20   0  203M  5044  4440 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.52 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 1149 root       20   0  203M  5044  4440 S  0.0  0.0  0:02.08 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
 1193 root       20   0  537M 16696  5664 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 1195 root       20   0  537M 16696  5664 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 1196 root       20   0  537M 16696  5664 S  0.0  0.0  0:18.24 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 1197 root       20   0  537M 16696  5664 S  0.0  0.0  0:01.20 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 1150 root       20   0  537M 16696  5664 S  0.0  0.0  0:20.05 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
 1151 root       20   0 19332  1312   944 S  0.0  0.0  1:06.54 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
 1152 root       20   0 34684  1744  1416 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.92 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind
 1166 dbus       20   0 34924  1944  1412 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork
 1153 dbus       20   0 34924  1944  1412 S  0.0  0.0  0:01.98 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork
 1156 root       20   0  123M  1684  1056 S  0.0  0.0  0:02.39 /usr/sbin/crond -n
 1164 avahi      20   0 27944   444   216 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
 1284 root       20   0  512M 10760  6508 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 1290 root       20   0  512M 10760  6508 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.35 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 1291 root       20   0  512M 10760  6508 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.05 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 1264 root       20   0  512M 10760  6508 S  0.0  0.0  0:07.67 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
 1331 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1334 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.31 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1336 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1337 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1341 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1319 polkitd    20   0  502M 10220  4560 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.68 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
 1840 root       20   0 82496  3608  2756 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.16 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see one `docker` daemon process? When you stop your containers the daemon process of course remains. If you want to completely stop docker you need to stop that one as well.

Comment: I see a lot of Python processes and I know the container was using a Python? and also I see more than 30GB memory used and there is nothin I have run on the machine right now...(before running the container only 2-3GB was used)

Comment: I see with "free -m" option the buffer cache is 42GB? (125G total; 885M  used; 82G free)

Comment: What image are you using? Could you provide a Dockerfile and/or your `docker run` command that you executed before that problem occurred?

Comment: I'm running - https://github.com/bgruening/docker-galaxy-stable
The command is - sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 -v /home/galaxy/galaxy_storage/:/export/ bgruening/galaxy-stable

Now the cache/buffer is even more - 125G (Total)       1.9G (used)            98G (buffer/cache)       122G(available)